# OrientDB remove all values from collection

Tags: orientdb

I noticed that the `UPDATE class REMOVE field = "item"` query only removes one matching item -

Is there a way to remove ALL matching values instead?

E.g. `["item1", "item2", "item2", "item2"]` => `["item1"]`

Mixed: `[{"test": "1"}, "item", "item"]` => `[{"test": 1}]`

Comment: Have you tried update class remove yourFieldName like 'item%'

Comment: @LasithaWeerasinghe That gives an `Encountered <LIKE>` error - https://i.gyazo.com/2c9b6ebd8b5c92798d8859527068a5d7.png

Comment: What do you keep in your collection? I mean are they strings, or any comlplex fata type.

Comment: @LasithaWeerasinghe Strings & documents/objects mainly.

Comment: Ok. Sorry I misunderstood your question earlier... It looks like orientdb removes one at a time from the collection with the remove command.. may be they have a different command for your requirement

Comment: What type of  collection are you using  ? Linklist, Linkset, Linkbag, LinkMap ?

Comment: @AlexB It says Embedded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this query

```
update class set field = field.removeAll("item2")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function in javascript:

```
var g=orient.getGraph();
var b=g.command("sql","select from Person");
for(j=0;j<b.length;j++)
{
  var array=[];
  var list= b[j].getProperty("items");

  for(i=0;i<list.length;i++)
  {
    if(list[i]!=item)
    {
      array.push(list[i]);
    }
    b[j].setProperty("items",array);
  }
}
```

Use this command to call the function in studio:

```
select expand(DeleteItems("item2")) from (select DeleteItems("item2"))
```

Regards,
Michela